# Insert from one table to another MySQL over PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a problem. I have 3 tables in MySQL two of it with 2 columns and one with tree columns like this : The first table has a column called `city` and one called `id`, the second one has a column called `categories` and a column called `id` and the third one has a column called `product`, one called `city_id` and one called `categories_id`. Now, the user can

1. add a product,
2. select city and
3. select categories on a web page.

But, when the data are inserted to the database I want to insert in the third table the product name and, not to insert the city and the categories names, but their ids from their tables. Can someone help me? (Sorry for my English) . Here is some code of what I done : (judete=city)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
 <?php
require 'conn.inc.php';

  $sql = "SELECT name FROM judete";

 if($result = $db->query($sql)){
//  print 'Selectare judete cu succes';

}
$sqlProd = "SELECT categorie FROM categorii ORDER BY categorie";
$resultProd = $db->query($sqlProd);

@$produs = $_POST['produs'];
@$categorie =$_POST['categorie'] ;
@$judet =$_POST['judet'] ;


if(isset($produs)&&!empty($produs)){
    $sqlTry = "INSERT INTO produse (produs, id_oras, id_categorie) VALUES ('$produs','$judet','$categorie')";
    if($db->query($sqlTry)){
        print 'Inserare cu succes!';

    }else{
        print 'Nu am putut sa inserez';
    }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adauga</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Introduceti produsul dorit : </h3>
<form method = "POST" action = "add.php">
Adauga produsul: <input type = 'text' name = 'produs' />
in categoria <select name = 'categorie'>
<?php while($row = $resultProd->fetch_object()){ print '<option>'.$row->categorie.'</option>';} ?>
</select>
din judetul
<select name = 'judet' >
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ print '<option>'.$row->name.'</option>'; }?>
</select>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'adauga'  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) -> `Returns the auto generated id used in the last query`

Comment: Try to make it clear::

 "But, when the data are inserted to the database to insert in the third table the product name and not the city and the categories names but their ids."

Answer (score 0):

you can first find their id then insert into or you can show the id in your html like `<option value = "1">'.$row->categorie.'</option>` then post the valu

Answer (score 0):

use option value in category list

```
<form method = "POST" action = "add.php">
Adauga produsul: <input type = 'text' name = 'produs' />
in categoria <select name = 'categorie'>
<?php while($row = $resultProd->fetch_object()){ print '<option value = "'.$row->cate_id.'">'.$row->categorie.'</option>';} ?>
</select>
din judetul
<select name = 'judet' >
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ print '<option value="'.$row->c_id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>'; }?>
</select>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'adauga'  />
</form>
```

add option value

```
<option value="'.$row->your_table_autoincrment_id.'"
```